# Python: Error Freezing ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, freeze

I get the following error trying to freeze a python script that imports ctypes:

```
 Warning: unknown modules remain: _bisect _ctypes _hashlib _heapq _locale _random _socket _ssl _struct _tkinter _weakref array binascii cStringIO collections datetime fcntl itertools math operator pyexpat readline select strop syslog termios time
```

, while ctypes is a builtin module in python2.5 and the path to ctypes is correctly recognized as in the following:

```
P ctypes                    /usr/local/lib/python2.5/ctypes/__init__.py
m ctypes._endian            /usr/local/lib/python2.5/ctypes/_endian.py
```

Is there any way to manually copy some files around and make this work? Has anybody ever successfully froze ctypes in a standalone binary?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use py2exe or something similar instead of freeze.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really out of date, but just in case anyone else stumbles onto this thread hoping to find an answer:

You may need to include some Python dynamic link libraries with your frozen distribution: e.g.

```
c:\\python\\dlls\\_ctypes.pyd.
```

Obviously, if you can use `PyInstaller` (or `py2exe`, etc.), that would be easier in almost all cases.